# How can I represent pages that are game levels in Schema.org?

Tags: schema.org, game-development, structured-data

I'd like to add Schema.org (with Microdata) to a browser-based game. The entire website would be considered a [VideoGame](http://schema.org/VideoGame), so it seems appropriate to mark up each page as a `VideoGame` in the `<html>` tag and label the "Home" link with `sameAs` property.

However, there are individual pages for each puzzle level (each "system"), as well as pages for collections of levels ("clusters"). How do I mark these up? `gameLocation` and `gameItem` are both vaguely equivalent properties, but are not good matches. I would love to be able to make each System and Cluster its own item instead of just a property of the parent `VideoGame`.

How do I represent individual levels of a game on each level's page?

Comment: Just posted an answer, but now I wonder: these pages for each puzzle level and for collections of levels: are these actual game pages (you play there), or are these pages more like a menu (you select a puzzle) or documentation (these levels are available, they work like this, etc.)? And if you actually play on these pages: are they really part of one game, or is maybe each of these puzzles its own game?

Comment: The puzzles are definitely part of the one game. You select puzzles from a list or a collection and play each on its own page; the results of solving a puzzle feed back into the rest of the game, progressing story and unlocking other puzzles. We're in closed alpha but you might get a better feel by looking at exploitzeroday.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `sameAs` property to link from each occurence of the `VideoGame` entity to the game’s homepage, you could give your game a URI and use this URI as identifier for each entity.¹ The [`url` property](http://schema.org/url) could be used to link to the game’s homepage. The [`sameAs` property](http://schema.org/sameAs) could be used to link to a Wikipedia page etc. about the game.

The [`VideoGame`](http://schema.org/VideoGame) entity represents the whole game, gives metadata about the game, etc., but this type itself is not meant to represent specific parts of your game.

If using its [`gameLocation` property](http://schema.org/gameLocation), you *do* have an own item (e.g., `Place`). The same with the [`gameItem` property](http://schema.org/gameItem) (e.g., `Thing`). These are properties of `VideoGame` because otherwise there would be no relation between the game and the locations/items it contains. Of course you could have a `Place`/`Thing` as top-level item and use the reverse² properties to reference the `VideoGame`, but that’s just an implementation detail, it doesn’t change the data.

However, Schema.org’s focus is of course not on video games, so most game content can’t be represented adequately. For example, `gameLocation` might not really be appropriate for puzzle game levels, unless e.g. a game character actually visits a puzzle in the game.

If you want to provide more detailed structured data about your game content, you’d have to use a different, ideally game-focused, vocabulary (and/or wait for or suggest a Schema.org extension).

---

¹ Microdata: `itemid` / RDFa Lite: `resource` / JSON-LD: `@id`
² No standard way in Microdata (`itemprop-reverse` proposed) / `rev` in RDFa (not RDFa Lite) / `@reverse` in JSON-LD